# Yelp Business API 2.0 Reviews with PHP not display

Tags: php, json, api

I am using the Yelp Business API v2.0 as documented at  https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/php/sample.php

My goal is to list reviews of a specific business, using PHP to make the API call and retrieve the json. I seem to only be able to fetch nothing, however, with the API. I have the script prepared to loop and display all reviews returned. How can I call the API to retrieve  review? give me a solution as soon as possible.
this is my output link:

http://www.sejixclients.com/mover/sample.php